# Non-const reference to non-const pointer to const char

Tags: c++, typecasting-operator

Why can't I take a reference to `s2` in `foo`? I'm compiling with gcc 5.1.0:

```
#include <cstring>

void foo(const char*& p)
{
    while (*p && *p <= '5')
        ++p;
}

int main()
{
    const char *s1 = "1234567890";
    char *s2 = new char[strlen(s1) + 1];
    strcpy(s2, s1);

    foo(s1);  // OK
    foo(s2);  // error

    return 0;
}
```

I compiled with:

```
$ g++ test_reference.cpp
```

The compiler gave me:

```
test_reference.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
test_reference.cpp:16:11: error: invalid initialization of non-const reference of type ‘const char*&’ from an rvalue of type ‘const char*’
     foo(s2);  // error
           ^
test_reference.cpp:3:6: note:   initializing argument 1 of ‘void foo(const char*&)’
 void foo(const char*& p)
      ^
```

Comment: Why are you using `char*`, `malloc`, `strlen` and `puts` in C++? You might as well be using C.

Comment: Use without the reference: `void foo(p_const_char_t p)`

Comment: @πάντα-ῥεῖ Using without the reference has another functionality.

Answer (score 3):

For simplicity, you are trying to do:

```
char* s = ...;
const char*& r = s;
```

The `const` here may be misleading. You would think this is equivalent to:

```
int i = 4;
const int& ri = i;
```

Which works. But these are not equivalent. `ri` here is a reference to a const type, but `r` is a reference to a pointer to `const char`, that is *not* a const type.

The ultimate issue is that `char*` and `char const*` are not *reference-related* (meaning that the types are either the same or in the same hierarchy). However, if your reference was a reference to a `const` type, it would work fine. That is:

```
const char* const& cr = s;
```

Basically, you can take an lvalue reference to a non-const type `T` only from a reference-related type or from a class that is convertible to a reference related type. But you can take an lvalue reference to a const type from a much wider source of expressions:

```
double d = 4.0;
int& ri = d;         // error: int, double aren't reference-related
const int& rci = d;  // OK
```

Answer (score 0):

You can cast it to const reference.

```
foo((const char *&) s2);
```

Comment: Thanks! This method worked perfectly. My question is edited, where I said that I correct third-party code, and do not try to make it a true C ++ code. By the way, I have tried a true C ++ equivalent **reinterpret_cast - it is not working**. So much for the equivalent of :) Seems something I do not understand.<br/>

Comment: @RomanM. Perhaps you can accept the answer if it worked. And show what you've exactly done using `reinterpret_cast` so that I can help.

Comment: I tested: `foo((char const *)s2);//err`, `foo((char const *&)s2); //OK`, `char const *&s3=s1;` `foo(s3);//OK`, `foo(static_cast<char const *&>(s2));//err`, `foo(static_cast<char const *>(s2));//err`, `foo(reinterpret_cast<char const *&>(s2));//err`, `foo(reinterpret_cast<char const *>(s2));//err`.